# Check if Dom Element is Native / no Custom Element

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element

Is there a way to check whether a Dom Element is a Native Element or a (not resolved) Custom Element without checking all Native tagNames in Javascript?

I Already thought of checking on `element.constructor === HTMLElement` but the `<main>` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main)) tag has that as it's top level class.

Basically I need a faster and less maintenance intensive way of checking for a native element.

Comment: You shoud check This question http://stackoverflow.com/q/43055481/4600982

Comment: Thank you, because of that post I found the solution! You just have to check for a hyphen in the tagName that's it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after the [comment of Supersharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211025/check-if-dom-element-is-native-no-custom-element#comment73503705_43211025) I found out that all custom elements tagName or the is attribute must contain a hyphen and native elements never do, so the best way to figure that out is to use this function:

```
function isCustomElement(element){
    if(element.tagName.indexOf("-") !== -1) {
        return true;
    }
    let isAttribute = element.getAttribute("is");
    if(isAttribute === null) {
        return false;
    }
    return isAttribute.indexOf("-") !== -1;
}
```

Simple as that.

[The W3C Standard documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/#custom-elements-core-concepts):

> They contain a hyphen, used for namespacing and to ensure forward compatibility (since no elements will be added to HTML, SVG, or MathML with hyphen-containing local names in the future).

Comment: Note that you should use `customElements.get()` too to check if the element is a *real*, defined custom element or just a non native one.

Comment: @Supersharp But i wrote in my post, that I want to detect unresolved custom elements also, since I need to check for nested custom elements inside the constructor of another custom element, where the nested custom elements might not be initialized at that time.

Comment: so you should check if the element is part of the native elements with hyphen: https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/#custom-elements-core-concepts

Comment: What do you mean exactly? The <button is="fancy-button"> case?
Otherwise there are no native elements with a hyphen: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp

It also says so in the w3c document:
They contain a hyphen, used for namespacing and to ensure forward compatibility (since no elements will be added to HTML, SVG, or MathML with hyphen-containing local names in the future).

Comment: For example `annotation-xml` is a valid (non-custom) element

Comment: Yes, inside of SVG and MathML but not in the HTML that browers use.
There will never be a native element with a hyphen in it's name.

Comment: Simple and brilliant solution!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:unresolved` pseudo-selector along with the `.constructor` property:

```js
var isUnresolved = function(selector) {
  var element = document.querySelector(selector + ':unresolved');
  try {
    return (/HTMLElement/).test(element.constructor);
  } catch (ignore) {
    return false;
  }
};
console.log(
  isUnresolved('foo-bar')
);
console.log(
  isUnresolved('main')
);
```

```html
<foo-bar></foo-bar>
<main></main>
```

Comment: Well this would work, but the problem here is that I already have the element, I can't just do a querySelector on it. And even then this would be waaaay slower than just checking every native tagName. Also the check for HTMLElement with a regex is much slower than my proposed element.constructor === HTMLElement which is basically the same. Due to Supersharp's comment I found out that all CustomElement's contain a hyphen whereas native elements never do.